# How do I model a non-owning view on some resource (not itself managed via shared_ptr), if not via raw pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, raw-pointer, ownership-semantics

`std::unique_ptr` is for exclusive ownership.

`std::shared_ptr` is for shared ownership.

So it looks like a raw pointer is left just the job of being a non-owning pointer, at least in good code.

But if I see a raw pointer somewhere, I actually don't know if it is truly just observing the pointee, or it is used somewhere to `delete` it or to create a `new` object.

Is there anything in the C++ language, or an accepted idiom, to model a non-owning view on some resource?

Comment: there is `gsl::owner`. If used consistently, all raw pointers are non-owning

Comment: What about [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)?

Comment: @Aziuth, the parenthesis in the title of the question rule it out.

Comment: The std::weak_ptr is meant as non-owning pointer.

Comment: @ÖöTiib, it needs the object to be already managed by a `std::shared_ptr`, doesn't it?

Comment: In your desired model, which part of the program would then actually do the ownership/memory management? That is, which problems do you have in particular for which `weak_ptr` or a reference don't work? Actually asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Yes, but by what it *is* managed? The raw pointer is worst because it is anything: array, iterator, one-past-last, dynamic object, reference.

Comment: You could use `template<T> observer_ptr = T*` (or use a class with similar interface as smart pointers) to explicitly imply that the raw pointer is non-owning.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, if a pointer is owning, then I'd make it a `std::unique_ptr`. As in, _if `std::unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` were used consistently, all raw pointers would be non-owning.

Comment: @Enlico yes but I understood its legacy. `std::owner` is much less intrusive than smart pointers. Its just a tagged raw pointer. You can use it on raw pointers managed by other code without the need to change that other code.

Comment: well ok, that last comment doesnt make sense :D. I don't delete it just for reference how its not a solution

Comment: If the raw pointer is on function boundaries (in function arguments or the return type), it's most probably time-bomb; A bug will show up sooner or later. The main job for raw pointers is to interface C API libraries, and language inter-operablity; that's why in good C++ code, raw pointer should only appear on function boundaries. Some complex data structures might still need raw pointers too, but those are corner cases for crazy library programmers.

Answer (score 1):

There is [std::experimental::observer_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) which is a pointer without ownership.